# C# Matrix Multiplication Library

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, namespaces, libraries, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to multiply 2 matrices.  I am `using System.Windows.Media`, but I am still getting the red squigglies under Matrix.  I can tell that `using System.Windows.Media` is registering, because it wants me to decide if I want to use `System.Windows.Media` or `System.Drawing` for my `Color`s.  Here is my code:

```
        Matrix matrix1 = new Matrix(5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30);
        Matrix matrix2 = new Matrix(2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12);

        // matrixResult is equal to (70,100,150,220,240,352) 
        Matrix matrixResult = Matrix.Multiply(matrix1, matrix2);

        // matrixResult2 is also 
        // equal to (70,100,150,220,240,352) 
        Matrix matrixResult2 = matrix1 * matrix2;
```

Any suggestions why the code is not picking up on `using System.Windows.Media`?  I have added the PresentationCore reference already.

Answer (score 0):

try putting this at the top of your .cs:

```
using Matrix = System.Windows.Media.Matrix;
```

This is probably occurring because you have System.Windows.Media as well as System.Drawing in your imports